# How to dispatch to main thread?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to execute some code from a non-main thread inside the main thread (UI thread) in .Net 6 with C#.

I've tried to use this code:

```
await Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    () => { }
);
```

This doesn't work, since `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread()` returns `null`.

My second try was:

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    () => { }
);
```

This fails, because `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView` throws a `System.InvalidOperationException`.

Another way should be:

```
await System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    () => { }
);
```

But the `System.Windows.Threading` namespace is not available for me, since I'm using .Net 6 and it's not longer supported in it.

**Any idea, how I can execute some code from a non-main thread inside the main-thread (UI thread)?**

Comment: You didn't specify which UI framework you are using. UWP, Winforms, WPF ?

Comment: Just don't ignore the InvalidOperationException, it is telling you that what you want to do is not possible.  Guessing at the reason is risky, but could be because you started the thread too soon and the main window is not initialized completely yet.  Or more typically because you let the user close it without stopping the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=net-7.0) is a good solution to switch to the main thread. But it's not implemented for all .Net app types.

For example, for a console app, there is no solution implemented.

But for Windows Forms, [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) works fine.

```
private SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;
```

Initialization inside, called inside the main thread:

```
_synchronizationContext = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();
```

After this, you can call from a different thread:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(_synchronizationContext);

... here we are in a separate thread

_synchronizationContext.Post(
    (state) => {
        ... this will be executed in the main thread
    },
    null);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to execute some code from a non-main thread inside the main thread (UI thread) in .Net 6 with C#.

I strongly recommend that you *don't*. It's far cleaner to have your `async` methods use something like `IProgress<T>` to indirectly update the UI as necessary. If you structure your code so that the main thread calls the background threads instead of the background threads manipulating the UI through the UI thread, then you'll end up with a much cleaner design where your logic is less tied to your UI controls.

That said, if you really want to, then the solution is to *capture* the dispatcher on the UI thread *before* the background work begins, and have the background work use *that* dispatcher (not the "current dispatcher") when posting work to the UI thread.

Comment: Even needing `Progress` should be fairly uncommon.  In almost all situations, returning values via the task's result should be sufficient.  Sometimes it means breaking up your operations into more smaller async methods so the UI can be updated in between each of them, which is also typically a desirable property for other reasons as well.

Comment: `IProgress<T>` is an interface, not a class. And the class `Progress<T>` does not implement a `Report` method. So I would have to use `IProgress<T>` for my non-main thread and implement the `Report` method by myself. And now, I have the same problem: It has to be run in the main thread. So your answer is not an answer for my question.

Comment: @Willy: Create the `Progress<T>` on the main thread. Then pass it to the background thread code, which takes a parameter of type `IProgress<T>`. It will take care of the thread marshalling for you.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Like mentioned before, `Progress<T>` does not have a `Report` method. So your solution can't work too.

Comment: @Willy - it has a `Report` method if you access it as an `IProgress<T>`. Of course it has a `Report` method - *it* implements `IProgress<T>`.

Comment: @Willy: Here's some more in-depth info: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#progress-reporting-optional

Comment: Sometimes it can be quite handy to run things on the UI thread for synchronization purposes. E.g. if you have commands raining in from some other thread, servicing like a TCP connection or a serial port. Instead of messing around with locks and mutexes you can just schedule your (quick) operations to run on the UI thread and you will not have race conditions or threading issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync
            (CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
            do something on UI thread
             });
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?